# Create document after submit with meteor-autoform

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using `meteor-autoform`. I create my form with

```
{{> quickForm collection="Messages" id="insertMessageForm" type="insert" fields="text"}}
```

It inserts the messages as it should but I also want to create a document in the Notification collection. How can I make sure an notification is created every time a new message is created? I want to create notification each time a new document is created in a collection all over my app. How can this be done smartest? Can I create an afterCreate signal or something?

Answer (score 0):

Use the meteor-core feature [`cursor.obsere`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe)

`lib/`

```
Messages.observe({
  added: function (doc) {
    Notifications.insert({ text: 'New Message: ' + doc.text })
  }
})
```

The `doc` variable holds the new document that was inserted.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using `Notifications.insert({userId: this.userId, text: 'New Message: ' + doc.text, createdAt: new Date});` but it seems `this.userId` is empty. Where should I place the code and how can I get the user id? I have also tried `Meteor.user()` but then I get the error `Exception in queued task: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions`

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my answer. `server/` is the place to put it. To get the user ID you can then use `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: In a file called `observe.js`? It seems I should use `Messages.find().observe()` instead of `Messages.observe()`. Is it correct?

Comment: Even though I have placed the code in `server/observe.js`, I still get the error `Exception in queued task: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.` when using `Meteor.userId()`

Comment: Sorry about that, I was wrong in the assumption that `Meteor.userId` can be called anywhere. You'll have to put the observer inside `client/`.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to create notification each time a new document is created in a
>   collection all over my app.

Then you should probably use this package : [`matb33:collection-hooks`](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks)

You will be able to create hooks for each of your collections to create a notification when a new document is inserted.

```
Comments.after.insert(function(userId, comment){
  Notifications.insert({
    userId: userId,
    text: comment.text,
    createdAt: comment.createdAt
  });
});
```

Be careful when using this package to not overly complicate your application logic and create circular hooks.

Comment: Why use a package when it's easily use a feature of a core package? [`cursor.observe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) does exactly what they want to do. Does this package provide any benefit over the core feature?